# Migrating 9 virtual machines to 1 server or pc

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, file-sharing, file-server, infrastructure

I have a build system set up which has 5 pcs and that has a total of 9 virtual machines using Hyper-V. I want to update this infrastructure and cut out the need for 5 physical pcs. Is there a way to host all 9 virtual machines on 1 pc or server so that I don't need all  physical pcs. If there is a server I can do this on, what are good examples of this kind of server? I dont want to be limited to just 9 virtual machines, I would like to create many more if needed and have the ability to modify, delete, or import/export virtual machines.

Any suggestions or guidance would be appreciated!!

Comment: Running multiple VMs on a machine is pretty simple, the information missing from the question is what the VMs are running and how much resource each needs, this would then be used as a guide to the size of the replacement machine.

Comment: you'll probably need lots of cpu cores + lots of RAM =lots of money

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: Each virtual machine will be running windows 10 along with 8GB Ram and 4 cores so what would the requirements be on a VMWare server? @hardillb

Comment: Based off the information I provided above, I can assume it would be but its needed and Im just trying to get an idea of what the specs on the VMWare server would look like @JaromandaX

Comment: It gives me a better understanding of what I am doing but doesnt entirely give me the answer. I want to find out my VMware server requirements based off info above. @NikitaKipriyanov

Comment: I'd say you'd want something with 80+GB RAM and 40+Cores minimum

Comment: @JaromandaX I figured it out. The server I am buying is a 600 series dell power edge rack server. 2 CPU with 16C\32T and it will have 126GB of RAM. It will be expensive but the company is buying it so shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov issue resolved! Thanks !

Comment: @hardillb issue resolved! Did tons of research and found the one I wanted